# How to get my model to only reference the keyword that i pass through?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

So im trying to make a Image Recogniton model based on labelling each image, i've already trained it on some data, the data is lighthouses and drones. However it is not trained on any other images, so it recognizes a ladder as a lighthouse and partly drone. I do not want this to happen, i'd like for the model to only compare the given image and the keyword (if possible). I do not want it to compare drones and lighthouses if the keyword i pass through is "lighthouse" it should only try and see if its a lighthouse.The issue im facing is that when i encounter an image i am untrained on it compares it to both lighthouses AND drone, But the keyword i passed through was "drone", I am still no to ML and Tensorflow so please don't crucify me for asking this question.

Full Code Snippet:
import tensorflow

```
import numpy
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from utils.n import n
from utils.c import c

def filter_classes(input_class, classes):
filtered_classes = list(filter(lambda x: x == input_class, classes))
return filtered_classes

def get_correct_images(question, images):
model = tensorflow.saved_model.load('./')
classes = filter_classes(question, \[ "lighthouse" ,  "drone" \])

    for url in images:
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
            img_data = response.read()
    
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data)).convert('RGB')
        img = img.resize((300, 300 * img.size[1] // img.size[0]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        inp_numpy = numpy.array(img)[None]
    
        inp = tensorflow.constant(inp_numpy, dtype='float32')
        class_scores = model(inp)[0].numpy()
    
        print("")
        print("class_scores", class_scores)
        print("Class : ", classes[class_scores.argmax()])
        print("Url: ", url)
```

Currently i have tried filtering using lamda:

```
def filter_classes(input_class, classes):
filtered_classes = list(filter(lambda x: x == input_class, classes))
return filtered_classes
```

and that then is suppose to filter it so that it only refrences its lighthouse or drone training not both:

```
def get_correct_images(question, images):
    model = tensorflow.saved_model.load('./')
    classes = filter_classes(question, [ "lighthouse" ,  "drone" ])

    for url in images:
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
            img_data = response.read()

        img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data)).convert('RGB')
        img = img.resize((300, 300 * img.size[1] // img.size[0]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        inp_numpy = numpy.array(img)[None]

        inp = tensorflow.constant(inp_numpy, dtype='float32')
        class_scores = model(inp)[0].numpy()

        print("")
        print("class_scores", class_scores)
        print("Class : ", classes[class_scores.argmax()])
        print("Url: ", url)
```

The output of this code is:

```
class_scores [0.9691824  0.03081765]
Class :  lighthouse
Url:  https:images.com/asset
```

What i expect (if possible) is that it should only return one [] ([0.9691824]) which would be lighthouse, instead of lighthouse and drone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using tensorflow model, and softmax layer as your output activation, the model will give you the probabilities of both the classes nevertheless.

You will get both the prob by default.
In this example, it tells you that the prob of the image being a lighthouse is 96% and the rest is drone.
One thing you can do is use:
np.argmax(model.predict(image))...

This will give you the index of the highest value in the array.
In this case, it will return 0, and for drones it will return 1.
So, you can say:
0: Lighthouse
1: Drone